# Establish MS SQL 2008 connection with JDBC using domain credentials

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, dns

I have three servers, App Server, Domain Controller and SQL Server. All of them are connected trough the local network.

What I am trying to accomplish is to successfully connect my app to the database using the credentials of an authorized domain user (ex: dom\dbadmin).

When I connect locally using those credentials, it works.

When I run the next code trough CMD on the APP Server with the right credentials and local IP, it works!

```
RUNAS /user:dom\dbadmin /netonly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

But when I try to connect with my app to the database with the following connection string it does not connect.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://10.20.30.110\MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=dBase;user=dom\dbadmin;password=!8899@te$t;
```

I have successfully made a connection to a identical DB but with SQL credentials and a remote ip and it works.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just not possible to make a connection with JDBC and domain credentials?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know - for passthrough authentication to work (SSPI in connection string) - you'll have to allow the domain controller to make the decision to allow you in with your credentials or not. In order to make this decision the controller will reply on your windows authentication with all imposed security restriction on computers within that domain. If you are logged on a computer as CORP\UserName then SSMS will not allow you to connect as someone else such as MyDomain\OtherUser. That is even if you know the correct password.

If you need an application to connect to an SQL Server you'll probably have to enable mixed authentication on the SQL Server and then generate an application password (not relying on Windows authentication).